# How to show $R(A \mid B)=R(A) + R(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Suppose $A$ be an $m \times n$ and $B$ be $m \times p$. Prove that

$$R(A \mid B)=R(A) + R(B)$$

where $R(A)=\{Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is the range of $A$.

Meyer's book ([Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra](http://www.cse.zju.edu.cn/eclass/attachments/2015-10/01-1446085870-145420.pdf)) question 4.2.9.

I cannot understand what $A \mid B$ is so I cannot prove this problem.

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: It is the range of $A$.

Comment: I would've guessed $A|B$ would be the augmented matrix obtained by taking $A$ and putting $B$ to the right, but the sizes of the matrices don't match up for that. Are you sure $B$ is not $n\times p$? (the pdf is taking forever to load so I can't check myself).

Comment: @Reveillark: I am sorry. I edited the size of $A$.

Comment: Great! So $A$ is $m\times (n+p)$ Then try to visualize what happens when you multiply $A|B$ by $x\in\ \mathbb{R}^{n+p}$. If you look at a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$ as a vector of length $n$ joined to one of length $p$, then multiplying by $A|B$ has $A$ multiply the $n$-vector and $B$ multiply the $p$ vector. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Reveillark: It does but how to show these two sets are subset of one another?

Comment: Let $x$ be in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$. Let $x'$ be the vector obtained from $x$ by deleting entries $n+1,\dots,p$. Let $x''$ be the vector obtained from $x$ by deleting entries $1,\dots,n$. Then $x=x'+x''$ and $(A|B)x=Ax'+Bx''$. Conversely, you can concatenate $2$ vectors of lengths $n$ and $p$ to get one of length $n+p$.